# SQL Server 2012 : The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012

While executing a stored procedure created in SQL Server 2008 R2 in SQL Server 2012 and retrieving the data through an Entity Data Model, this error occurs:

> The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

The stored procedure is executing successfully in SQL Server Management Studio 2012. But the issue is when coming back to the Entity Data Model.

Anyone encountered this kind of an issue??

Comment: Check the mapping files to verify what the entityframework created properties actually is expecting for the relevant field. I've seen that message before when the entityframework hadn't mapped datetime2 correctly

Comment: Did you generate the model on server with higher version than now connected by EDM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the **compatibility level** of that database you're running against?

Check using

```
SELECT compatibility_level 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'YourDatabaseNameHere'
```

`DATETIME2` was introduced in SQL Server **2008** - so if that level is below 100 (which is SQL Server 2008), then the `DATETIME2` data type isn't available yet.

If the database was upgraded from a SQL Server 2005 instance, most likely, it's compatibility level is still at 90 (SQL Server 2005) and thus the `DATETIME2` datatype isn't available yet.

You can upgrade your database compatibility level to more recent values using:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseNameHere
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100;
```

where `level = 100` is SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2, and `level = 110` is SQL Server 2012

Comment: OP states that the SP runs successfully form SSMS.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: true - but we don't see what he's doing in in the stored procedure. I've had issues like this with Entity Framework when going against 2005 databases - that's why I'm asking if that might be the cause ....

Comment: @marc_s If this was the issue then it will not execute successfully in SSMS right???

Comment: @marc_s For the SQL Server 2008 R2 database where I created the sp, I checked the compatibility level from your above query. The compatibilty level there is 90 only for that database.I am not talking about the 2012 db. When I use that db the data is retrieved to the entity data model and no error is there