# Insert DateTime into SQL Server 2005

Tags: linq2db

How to configure `linq2db` to use types for `SQL Server 2005`? Now I'm trying to do an insert command InsertWithIdentity,

> I get the error: "The version of SQL Server in use does not support
>   datatype 'datetime2'".

For `DateTime` columns I put attribute `[Column ("DataSert", DataType = DataType.DateTime)]`, does not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2012 : The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776082/sql-server-2012-the-version-of-sql-server-in-use-does-not-support-datatype-da)

Comment: To  Roman Mik: Does not help. Sql give error: Incorrect syntax near '100'.

Comment: @RomanMik That's not the same thing. Datetime2 was added in SQL Server 2008 and for 2012 changing compatibility level will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following connectionString:

```
<add name="MyName.2005" connectionString="..." providerName="SqlServer" />
```

or

```
<add name="MyName" connectionString="..." providerName="SqlServer.2005" />
```